# Añadir celda a una sección elegida de una Table View en Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewcell

como puedo controlar a qué Sección de una Table View se añade un objeto celda. Es decir, al añadir una celda a la Table (los datos los capturo desde un textfield) poder decidir añadir la celda a la Sección 1 o a la 2, 3...o a la que el usuario desee, ya que las secciones también las creo previamente.
Mi problema es que o todas las celdas aparecen en todas las secciones o solo aparecen en la última sección añadida.
¿Existe algún método del Delegate para ello?
Gracias

```
class miClase {
var arrayContenido: [miClase] = []

var nombreProducto: String 
var nombreCategoria: String

init(nombre: String) {
self.nombre = nombre
  }

init(nombreCategoria: String) {
self.nombreCategoria = nombreCategoria
  }
}


// Defino un protocolo para crear los objetos y enviarlos al VC de la TableView
protocol miProtocolo {
func añadirCategoria(nuevaCategoria: miClase)
func añadirProducto(nuevoProducto: miClase)
}


class ViewControllerNuevoProducto {
var miDelegado: miProtocolo?

// Button para añadir una sección nueva
@IBAction func añadirCategoria(_ sender: Any) {
var nameCategory = ""
    
if let name = textFieldSeccion.text {
   nameCategory = name
  }
    
 let sección = miClase(nombreCategoria: nameCategory)
 miDelegado?.añadirCategoria(nuevaCategoria: sección)
}

// Button para crear un nuevo producto
@IBAction func buttonAgregarMesa(_ sender: Any) {
var nombre = ""

if let name = textFieldProducto.text {
   nombre = name
  }
    
 let producto = miClase(nombreProducto: nombre)
 // Si añado al array de la clase desde aquí, en mi Table View no se como acceder
// producto.arrayContenido.append(producto)
    
 miDelegado?.añadirProducto(nuevoProducto: producto)
}

}



class VCMesasTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate, miProtocolo {

var arraySecciones: [miClase] = []

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
let envio = segue.destination as! ViewControllerNuevoProducto
envio.miDelegado = self
 }

// Extension de mi Protocolo Delegado
extension VCTableView {
// Implementacion del metodo de para añadir categorías y productos

// Aqui me surge el primer problema ya que no se me almacena en el array de la clase
func añadirProducto(nuevoProducto: miClase) {

arraySecciones.append(nuevoProducto)

self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func añadirCategoria(nuevaCategoria: miClase) {
arraySecciones.append(nuevaCategoria)
self.tableViewMesas.reloadData()
}
}   // Fin extension de mi protocolo


extension VCTableView {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return arraySecciones.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return arraySecciones[section].arrayContenido.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let miCelda = tableViewMesas.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "miCelda", for: indexPath) as! VCTableViewCell

miCelda.labelNombreCelda.text =
      arraySecciones[indexPath.section].arrayContenido[indexPath.row].nombre

return miCelda
}

}
```

Para empezar creo que no se está usando el array que tengo en mi clase que daría como resultado los Productos. Ya que en el array declarado en el VC, sería para añadir las secciones, pero al parecer almacena ambas cosas.
Como resultado es que o bien todas las celdas aparecen en todas las secciones, o simplemente en la ultima sección añadida.
La idea es poder elegir a que sección (previamente creada) añadir cada producto nuevo creado.
Sin todo este lio de las secciones la Table View funciona perfectamente.

Espero se entienda, gracias

Comment: Cómo tienes estas funciones `numberOfSections` y `cellForRowAt indexPath`?

Comment: numberOfSections tengo: arraySecciones.count. 
cellForRowAt tengo: miCelda.textLabel.text = arraySecciones[indexPath.section].arrayContenido[indexPath.row].nombre  Tengo una clase con 2 variables, nombre y nombreCategoria. En la misma clase arrayContenido del tipo de la clase. En mi VC tengo arraySecciones del mismo tipo para así poder acceder a arrayContenido. Imagina que hablamos de una tienda, donde el usuario crea por ej 3 secciones, carne, pescado y bebidas. A hora de crear un producto, por ej Pollo, pueda decidir enviarlo a la sección carne. No lo encuentro en la doc de Swift :-(

Comment: Si, ahora mismo hago

Comment: @Ruben normalmente el nombre de las clases y protocolos por estándar deben empezar por mayúscula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le veo un problema esta parte de código porque estas devolviendo el número total de filas, es decir si hay 20 registros vas a tener 20 secciones.

```
return arraySecciones.count
```

Podrías almacenar en un array los valores de las secciones así:

```
var miarray1 = [String]()
for item in arraySecciones {
    miarray1.append(item.nombreCategoria)
}
```

Como resultado podrías tener:

```
["Section1", "Section2", "Section1"]
```

Como ves en tu código dices que tienes 3 secciones lo que es falso porque ***Section1*** se repite. Entonces eliminamos las secciones repetidas:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {//Este código es de Hackingswift.com
    func removingDuplicates() -> [Element] {
        var addedDict = [Element: Bool]()
        
        return filter {
            addedDict.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil
        }
    }
    
    mutating func removeDuplicates() {
        self = self.removingDuplicates()
    }
}
```

Llamamos a esa función:

```
let miarray = miarray1.removingDuplicates()
```

Y obtendrías:

```
["Section1", "Section2"]
```

Entonces ahora si sabes cuantas secciones hay:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return miarray.count
    }
```

Para mostrar los valores de acuerdo a cada sección puedes hacer esto:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if arraySecciones[indexPath.row].nombreCategoria == miarray[indexPath.section]//Compruebas nombreCategoria sea igual al array de las secciones {
    //Si es igual asignas los valores
    tutext.text = arraySecciones[indexPath.row].nombreProducto
}
```

Comment: Mi problema era que no recorría el array para poder almacenar en la sección deseada. Me sirvió el primer fragmento que me pusiste para guiarme, gracias!